# Why does these two not return the same value and how can i make them do that?

Tags: bash

I have a zip file on my desktop which is 1440 bytes in size. The following is the sha1 of it.

```
openssl sha1 "$HOME/Desktop/file.zip"
> SHA1(/Users/loveborgstrom/Desktop/file.zip)= eaf08d01087617721555eeca9867b13e74c8e7df
```

Long story short, i need to store this file inside of a script. To do this i converted the file into base64. However when i try to print it it fails. I noticed that the printed file has a different sha1 than the original.

My question is why does this leave the file intact

```
cat "$HOME/Desktop/file.zip" | base64 | base64 -D | openssl sha1
> eaf08d01087617721555eeca9867b13e74c8e7df
```

but not this

```
a="$(cat "$HOME/Desktop/file.zip")"; echo -n "${a}" | base64 | base64 -D | openssl sha1
> ccc23bb28dd6ff27bcd4de7739c931f5870d06e7
```

If i print each of these to a file the first one is intact at 1440 bytes and is possible to extract. The other one however is only 1086 bytes in size...

Im confused why some of the content disappear, and would like to know how to stop that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Turs out bash variabels has some limitations, making it difficult to deal with binary data. zsh does however support this.

See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278644) for more details

Comment: Also, `echo` appends a newline character at the end that wasn't there in the original.

Comment: @GordonDavisson of course, `-n` is a extension (seemingly available in both GNU and FreeBSD at least), and I think is at best not specified by POSIX

Comment: @EricRenouf Oops, I missed the `-n`. However, `-n` is not really standard, and some implementations of `echo` will just print "-n" as part of the output (and also print the newline at the end). According to [the POSIX standard for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), "If the first operand is `-n`, or if any of the operands contain a <backslash> character, the results are implementation-defined." To portably print a string without newline, use `printf` instead (e.g. `printf "%s" "${a}"`).